# How to find Future implementation in scala.concurrent?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I am trying to understand what exactly happens, when I call

```
val f = scala.concurrent.Future {... // my body function }
```

The [code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L1) of `object Future` defines `apply` methods as follows:

```
def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit execctx: ExecutionContext): Future[T] =
   impl.Future(body)
```

Unfortunately I do not see where the *impl* is defined in the code (and what it exactly does). My question is where the *impl* is defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[impl is just a package](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl) from which Future object borrows [implementation class](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Future.scala).

[image]

Since Future object lives in the same `concurrent` package it could address impl package effortlessly (no explicit imports required)

Comment: Great! Thank you. I should have got it by myself. I do not know how I missed it :)